# contar cantidad de veces que se repite un carácter en un array

Tags: javascript

```js
let array="qeweewqeq";
let string="e";     //  no quiero asignarle un valor
let count=[];
for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  if (array[i].toLowerCase()==string) {
    count.push(i)
  }
}
console.log("caracter: "+string+" repetido"+" "+count.length+" veces");
```

no se como hacer para que solo me muestre que caracter se repite mas veces, y no tener que asignarle yo un valor para que busque ese carter.

Comment: claro, busco que me ayuden a comprender el ejercicio, ya que tengo ese problema que no se como resolverlo.

Comment: let array="qeweewqeq";
let string="";
let count=[];
for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  for (let j=i+1;j<array.length;j++) {
    if (array[i].length!=array[j].length) {
      continue;
    }
    if (array[i].length==array[j].length) {
      count=array[i]=array[j]+1;
      string=count;
      //count=1;
    }
  }
}
console.log("caracter: "+string+" repetido"+" "+count.length+" veces");



si guardo count=1; no me da el resultado correcto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes dividir la palabra y separarla por letras con el numero de veces que se repite cada letra y una vez tienes las letras de la palabra y el número de veces que se repite deberás buscar cual es la que tiene el máximo de veces repetidas:

```js
const array = 'qeweewqeq';

const wordByLetters = array.split('').reduce((acc, current) => {
  acc[current] = acc[current] ? acc[current] + 1 : 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const [letter, timesRepeated] = Object.entries(wordByLetters).find(([_, value]) => {
    return value === Math.max(...Object.values(wordByLetters));
});

console.log(`caracter: "${letter}" repetido ${timesRepeated} veces`);
```

Si hubiera dos letras con el mismo valor máximo este método `find` solo devolverá la primera de las letras.
Sin embargo si quisieras en caso de tener varias con el mismo número máximo deberás cambiar el `find` por un `filter` y tener en cuenta que devolverá un array así que habrá que recorrerlo como tal.